# How can I ask autocompletion to ignore buffers matching a pattern?

Tags: autocompletion

I make use of vim's `<C-n>`/`<C-p>` auto-completion menu with the default `complete` setting `.,w,b,u,t,i`.

This generally works great, but I'd like to have Vim ignore buffers from a certain directory, even though they are loaded. For example, a directory containing large log files does not need to be scanned for completion (and it slows down Vim to do so).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is no option for that so no, not without writing your own alternative completion function.

Comment: I skimmed the documentation for the alternative completion function. It mentions allowing setting a function for finding the start of the text to be completed, and a function to actually find the matches, but I don't see mention of specifying the files to be searched through. Do you think it's possible to implement it with the completefunc?

Comment: Searching through buffers and files, and skipping some of them, would be the responsibility of the second function.

Comment: Thank you! Let me take a closer look.